# remove duplicates on left table while keeping duplicates on right table SELECT JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join, duplicates

I'm trying to JOIN two tables and output them so that I don't get any duplicates from the first table. In the first table there is no duplicates on the id where i'm joining the two tables, but in the second table there can be several instances.

I have tried "GROUP BY" on the id in the first table but that of course eliminates the duplicates in the second table..

Should I try to use some sort of nested SELECT or do what would you suggest?

It seems that I'm stuck and I would appreciate all help I could get.

Here is my query:

```
$time_query = "SELECT time.id, time.time_in, time.time_out, time.comment, time.user_id, time_break.break_in AS break_in, time_break.break_out AS break_out, time_break.time_id AS time_id 
            FROM `time`
            LEFT JOIN time_break
            ON time.id = time_break.time_id
            WHERE time.time_out != '' AND time.user_id= $uid
            ORDER BY time.id ASC
```

Comment: This is not what SQL does. You need to "format the output" by suppressing some repeated values. That should be done in the product that accepts the $time_query result. NOT in the sql that supplies the result. By the way, repetition of values the time table columns is NECESSARY to provide the requested order.

Comment: The word `time` is used by SQL itself, so I would suggest you use a table alias to avoid possible confusion.

Comment: I'm with Aknosis - doesn't make sense why you want a bunch of records with null time.id unless its for display purposes / cobol style header to transaction records in which case this is an ETL question not an sql question

Answer (score 0):

I am opposed to what seems like "unnatural" manipulation of results using SQL, but so that you may see how awkward this is here is an approach to suppressing (or "hiding") values that you don't want to see.

In my view this should be done at the "presentation layer", but in MySQL you may use variables to consider previous row values:

```
SELECT
      @row_num :=IF(@prev_value = t.id , @row_num + 1, 1) AS RowNumber
    , t.id
    , IF(@row_num = 1,t.id, '')       AS t_id
    , IF(@row_num = 1,t.time_in, '')  AS time_in
    , IF(@row_num = 1,t.time_out, '') AS time_out
    , IF(@row_num = 1,t.comment, '')  AS comment
    , IF(@row_num = 1,t.user_id, '')  AS user_id
    , tb.break_in                     AS break_in
    , tb.break_out                    AS break_out
    , tb.time_id                      AS time_id
    , @prev_value := t.id
FROM `time` AS t
LEFT JOIN time_break AS tb ON t.id = tb.time_id
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @row_num :=1,  @prev_value :='') vars
WHERE t.time_out <> ''
AND t.user_id = @UID
ORDER BY
      t.id ASC
    , t.time_in ASC
    , tb.break_in ASC
```

**NB** When using the result of such a query, you should **not** order by any of the columns where some values are suppressed/hidden.

Comment: OK, I understand that this is not the way to go. Thank you @Used_By_Already for setting me straight. As you suggested I will try to find a better approach by formating the output instead.